# MVC 5 AddView Template Empty Model class IEnumerable<Item> Error An item with the same index has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a simple Asp.Net MVC application. When I try to add empty view named "List" with model class "Product", its give me this:

There was an error running the selected code generator "An item with the same index has already been added"

I use latest stable versions of Ninject, Ninject.MVC3, Moq.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;
    public ProductController (IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

IProductRepository code

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> Products { get;}
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have reinstall *Visual Studio* and this fix problem.

Comment: Verify if IProductRepository has two properties with the same key (not case sensitive). If you have Id and ID it will throw that error.

Comment: IProductRepository has only one property IEnumerable<Product> Products { get;}

Comment: At what point does this error happen? In the code or in the view? After a post?

Comment: @acastr7 it happened in the code. _Right-click on the List action method -> Add View -> Template to  Empty -> Product  for  the  Model Class and  Use A Layout Page box is checked_. After that I have error